# Where to store comments on videos

Tags: php

I'm building a video rating community and want to add comments ability for each video. I have 2 tables - one for the users and another for the videos. The videos table contains the following fields (id, username, title, description, url, thumbUp, thumbDown). I am wondering if I should create a new table for the comments or use the existing videos? Also, how would I design that table if it needs to be a separate one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a separate table.  I would suggest a schema like the following:

- **id**

  - unique id for the comment
- **user_id**

  - the user who posted the comment (foreign key)
- **video_id**

  - the video on which the comment was posted (foreign key)
- **timestamp**

  - when the comment was posted
- **comment**

  - the comment data

Comment: Thank you! I will do that! Can you also advise how would I limit a user to be able to vote only once per video?

Comment: @sixli:  See what the result of this query is: `SELECT id FROM comments WHERE user_id = ? AND video_id = ?`.

Comment: One more question - I now want to list out the comments via prepared statements - but am not sure how to handle an assoc array with them. Here is my code:     $fetchComments = $cnx -> prepare("SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE video_id=? LIMIT 1");
  $fetchComments -> bind_param('s', $row['id']);
  $fetchComments -> execute();
  $fetchComments -> store_result();
  $fetchComments -> bind_result($vid_comment);

  if ($fetchComments -> num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vid_comment)){
                            echo $row['comment'];
 }  
}  
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes create a new table for comments. Unless You're using something like a nosql database (like mongo), in which you'll probably be better served saving comments in the videos table

Comment: Thanks! Can you also advise how would I limit a user to be able to vote only once per video?

Comment: create a unique constraint on user_id, video_id. That'll prevent the db from writing more than one comment. I'd suggest also putting in the validation in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new table comments with fields video_id, user_id, comment. Foreign keys are video_id to the video table, and user_id to the user table. For voting only once you can set constrain on unique to the fields of video_id and user_id